# Google Tag Manager for iOS - Carthage

Tags: google-tag-manager, carthage

After taking a look to Google Tag Manager for iOS, it seems the only way to integrate it is by using CocoaPods.

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5

My company use Carthage, though. Would it be possible to use Carthage instead? Did any of you manage to do it?

Comment: was it solved using carthage?

Comment: No. I could not make it work. Actually, we ended up using Cocoapods instead.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like installing it with CocoaPods is the only way to integrate it.

If you want other way, You can create a demo app and install Google Tag Manager in it using CocoaPods and then copy the framework file into your project. It worked for me.

Comment: can you please help me with integrating this in iOS project?

Comment: Follow this https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/ . If you still need help, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We were facing issues integrating the iOS SDK manually since we are using Carthage and these SDK's are provided using Cocopods. So reached out to you to understand how you managed to  build the project. We are now able to build the project by including the frameworks/source code manually.

Comment: @manishsharma93 I suppose that you don't have a step for step guide getting this working without Pods. I really wish Google would embrace Carthage